# Como verificar se a opção digitada está entre as opções válidas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo o exercício 28 da lista de Estrutura De Decisão do site [PythonBrasil] (https://wiki.python.org.br/EstruturaDeDecisao) porém quando incluo o código para quando o usuário escolher uma opção inválida finalizar o programa todas as opções que eu escolho (até mesmo as certas) finaliza o programa.

Código com o provável erro:

```py
if tipo_da_carne.lower() != "f" or tipo_da_carne.lower() != "a" or tipo_da_carne.lower() != "p":
    print()
    print("{}".format("="*64))
    print("{}Opção Invalida".format(" "*25))
    print("{}".format("="*64))
    print()
    sys.exit()
```

**Código Completo:**

```py
import sys

print()
print("{}".format("="*64))
print("{}Seja bem vindo ao Supermercado Tabajara".format(" "*12))
print("{}".format("="*64))
print()

tipo_da_carne = str(input("Precione F para File Duplo, A para Alcatra ou P para Picanha: "))

if tipo_da_carne.lower() != "f" or tipo_da_carne.lower() != "a" or tipo_da_carne.lower() != "p":
    print()
    print("{}".format("="*64))
    print("{}Opção Invalida".format(" "*25))
    print("{}".format("="*64))
    print()
    sys.exit()

qtd_carne = float(input("Digite a quantidade que vai querer: "))
tipo_pagamento = str(input("Caso tenha o cartão tabajara precione C ou D para dinheiro: "))

print()
print("{}".format("="*64))
print("{}Nota Fiscal".format(" "*26))
print("{}".format("="*64))
print()

#File Duplo
if tipo_da_carne.lower() == "f":
    print("Tipo da carne: File Duplo")
    print("Quantidade: {}".format(round(qtd_carne, 2)))

    #Calcular desconto por Kg
    if qtd_carne <= 5:
        preço_file_duplo = qtd_carne * 4.90
    else:
        preço_file_duplo = qtd_carne * 5.80

    #Preço Bruto
    print("Preço total: R${}".format(round(preço_file_duplo, 2)))

    #Catão Tabajara
    if tipo_pagamento.lower() == "c":
        print("Tipo de pagamento: Catão Tabajara")
        valor_desconto = preço_file_duplo * 0.05
        valor_pagar = preço_file_duplo - valor_desconto
        print("Desconto: R${}".format(round(valor_desconto, 2)))
        print("Preço Final: R${}".format(round(valor_pagar, 2)))
    else:
        print("Tipo de pagamento: Dinheiro")
        print("Desconto: R$0.0")
        print("Preço Final: R${}".format(round(preço_file_duplo, 2)))

#Alcatra
if tipo_da_carne.lower() == "a":
    print("Tipo da carne: Alcatra")
    print("Quantidade: {}".format(round(qtd_carne, 2)))

    #Calcular desconto por Kg
    if qtd_carne <= 5:
        preço_alcatra = qtd_carne * 4.90
    else:
        preço_alcatra = qtd_carne * 5.80

    #Preço Bruto
    print("Preço total: R${}".format(round(preço_alcatra, 2)))

    #Catão Tabajara
    if tipo_pagamento.lower() == "c":
        print("Tipo de pagamento: Catão Tabajara")
        valor_desconto = preço_alcatra * 0.05
        valor_pagar = preço_alcatra - valor_desconto
        print("Desconto: R${}".format(round(valor_desconto, 2)))
        print("Preço Final: R${}".format(round(valor_pagar, 2)))
    else:
        print("Tipo de pagamento: Dinheiro")
        print("Desconto: R$0.0")
        print("Preço Final: R${}".format(round(preço_alcatra, 2)))

#Picanha
if tipo_da_carne.lower() == "p":
    print("Tipo da carne: Picanha")
    print("Quantidade: {}".format(round(qtd_carne, 2)))

    #Calcular desconto por Kg
    if qtd_carne <= 5:
        preço_picanha = qtd_carne * 4.90
    else:
        preço_picanha = qtd_carne * 5.80

    #Preço Bruto
    print("Preço total: R${}".format(round(preço_picanha, 2)))

    #Catão Tabajara
    if tipo_pagamento.lower() == "c":
        print("Tipo de pagamento: Catão Tabajara")
        valor_desconto = preço_picanha * 0.05
        valor_pagar = preço_picanha - valor_desconto
        print("Desconto: R${}".format(round(valor_desconto, 2)))
        print("Preço Final: R${}".format(round(valor_pagar, 2)))
    else:
        print("Tipo de pagamento: Dinheiro")
        print("Desconto: R$0.0")
        print("Preço Final: R${}".format(round(preço_picanha, 2)))

print()
print("{}".format("="*64))
print()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como já dito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/428696/112052), o problema é usar `or` quando na verdade deveria usar `and`. Usando `or`, vai entrar no `if` se qualquer uma das condições for verdade (ou seja, se digitar `f`, não vai ser diferente de `f`, mas vai ser diferente de `a`, o que já é suficiente para entrar no `if`). Já usando `and`, só entra no `if` se todas forem verdadeiras (ou seja, se a opção for diferente de `a`, `f` e `p`).

Mas na verdade daria para fazer de forma mais simples. Para começar, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário. Além disso, vi que você usa várias vezes o [método `lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower), mas já que só vai usar a versão minúscula da string, use-o apenas uma vez, logo depois do `input`. Então você poderia simplesmente fazer assim:

```
tipo_da_carne = input("Pressione F para File Duplo, A para Alcatra ou P para Picanha: ").lower()

if tipo_da_carne not in ('a', 'f', 'p'):
    # opção inválida...
```

O `not in` verifica se o `tipo_da_carne` não está entre as opções desejadas. Se não estiver, entra no `if` (ou seja, a opção é inválida).

---

Há ainda outras melhorias a se fazer, segue algumas sugestões abaixo:

Ao digitar a quantidade de carne, você pode capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) (que ocorre caso não seja digitado um número). Algo assim:

```
while True:
    try:
        qtd_carne = float(input("Digite a quantidade que vai querer: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('digite um número válido')
```

Ou seja, enquanto não for digitado um número, ele continua pedindo que digite novamente. Se digitar um número válido, o `break` sai do `while` e continua executando o restante do programa.

Obs: se a quantidade só pode ser um número inteiro, prefira usar [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) em vez de [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float).

A impressão das mensagens pode ser encapsulada em uma função:

```
def print_msg(msg):
    print()
    print('=' * 64)
    print('{:^64}'.format(msg))
    print('=' * 64)
    print()
```

Repare no trecho `{:^64}`: ele centraliza a mensagem, assim você não precisa colocar uma quantidade fixa de espaços antes do texto (veja mais na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) sobre os formatos aceitos por `format`). Desta forma, você só precisaria chamar:

```
print_msg("Seja bem vindo ao Supermercado Tabajara")
```

Que o [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) "se vira" para centralizar a mensagem.

Outra coisa é que o trecho que imprime o preço e demais informações está bem repetitivo (até o preço é o mesmo), então daria para simplificar também. Você poderia usar [dicionários](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) para mapear as letras `a`, `f` e `p` para os respectivos nomes das carnes, e outro para mapear os meios de pagamento.

O código ficaria assim:

```
def print_msg(msg):
    print()
    print('=' * 64)
    print('{:^64}'.format(msg))
    print('=' * 64)
    print()

carnes = {
    'a': 'Alcatra',
    'f': 'Filé Duplo',
    'p': 'Picanha'
}

meios_pagto = {
    'c': 'Cartão Tabajara',
    'd': 'Dinheiro'
}

print_msg("Seja bem vindo ao Supermercado Tabajara")
tipo_da_carne = input("Pressione F para File Duplo, A para Alcatra ou P para Picanha: ").lower()

if tipo_da_carne not in carnes: # se tipo não é uma das chaves do dicionário "carnes"
    print_msg('Opção inválida')
else:
    while True:
        try:
            qtd_carne = float(input("Digite a quantidade que vai querer: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('digite um número válido')

    tipo_pagamento = input("Caso tenha o cartão tabajara precione C ou D para dinheiro: ").lower()
    if tipo_pagamento not in meios_pagto:
        print_msg('Meio de pagto inválido')
    else:
        print_msg('Nota Fiscal')
        print("Tipo da carne: {}".format(carnes[tipo_da_carne]))
        print("Quantidade: {:.2f}".format(qtd_carne))
        # Calcular desconto por Kg
        if qtd_carne <= 5:
            preco = qtd_carne * 4.90
        else:
            preco = qtd_carne * 5.80

        #Preço Bruto
        print("Preço total: R${:.2f}".format(preco))
        print("Tipo de pagamento: {}".format(meios_pagto[tipo_pagamento]))

        # Cartão Tabajara
        if tipo_pagamento == "c":
            valor_desconto = preco * 0.05
            print("Desconto: R${:.2f}".format(valor_desconto))
            preco -= valor_desconto # subtrai o desconto do preço
        else:
            print("Desconto: R$0.0")

        print("Preço Final: R${:.2f}".format(preco))

        print()
        print("=" * 64)
        print()
```

`tipo_da_carne not in carnes` verifica se o tipo da carne não é uma das chaves do dicionário `carnes` (que no caso são `a`, `f` e `p`). Repare também que na hora de imprimir o nome da carne, usei `carnes[tipo_da_carne]`, que é o nome correspondente à opção digitada.

Também usei um dicionário para os meios de pagamento, para verificar se a opção digitada é válida e posteriormente para imprimir o respectivo nome. Repare também que não usei `sys.exit()`: em vez disso, só coloquei um bloco `else` no primeiro `if`.

Por fim, usei `{:.2f}` para formatar o preço e demais valores arredondados para 2 casas decimais.

E também simplifiquei um pouco o último `if`, que imprime informações diferentes conforme o meio de pagamento (os trechos em comum - ou seja, o que executa independente do meio de pagamento, como a impressão do nome e o preço final - tirei do `if`/`else`).

---

Se estiver usando Python >= 3.6, pode ainda trocar o `format` por [*f-strings*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Então em vez de `print("Quantidade: {:.2f}".format(qtd_carne))`, você pode usar `print(f"Quantidade: {qtd_carne:.2f}")`:

```
def print_msg(msg):
    print()
    print('=' * 64)
    print(f'{msg:^64}')
    print('=' * 64)
    print()

carnes = {
    'a': 'Alcatra',
    'f': 'Filé Duplo',
    'p': 'Picanha'
}

meios_pagto = {
    'c': 'Cartão Tabajara',
    'd': 'Dinheiro'
}

print_msg("Seja bem vindo ao Supermercado Tabajara")
tipo_da_carne = input("Pressione F para File Duplo, A para Alcatra ou P para Picanha: ").lower()

if tipo_da_carne not in carnes:
    print_msg('Opção inválida')
else:
    while True:
        try:
            qtd_carne = float(input("Digite a quantidade que vai querer: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('digite um número válido')

    tipo_pagamento = input("Caso tenha o cartão tabajara precione C ou D para dinheiro: ").lower()
    if tipo_pagamento not in meios_pagto:
        print_msg('Meio de pagto inválido')
    else:
        print_msg('Nota Fiscal')
        print(f"Tipo da carne: {carnes[tipo_da_carne]}")
        print(f"Quantidade: {qtd_carne:.2f}")
        # Calcular desconto por Kg
        if qtd_carne <= 5:
            preco = qtd_carne * 4.90
        else:
            preco = qtd_carne * 5.80

        #Preço Bruto
        print(f"Preço total: R${preco:.2f}")
        print(f"Tipo de pagamento: {meios_pagto[tipo_pagamento]}")

        # Cartão Tabajara
        if tipo_pagamento == "c":
            valor_desconto = preco * 0.05
            print(f"Desconto: R${valor_desconto:.2f}")
            preco -= valor_desconto
        else:
            print("Desconto: R$0.0")

        print(f"Preço Final: R${preco:.2f}")

        print()
        print("=" * 64)
        print()
```

Comment: Desculpe pelos varios erro no codigo sou novo na programação e estou começando a aprender agora, com certeza a sua ajuda para simplificar o codigo vai me ajudar muito a evoluir na area, Obrigado !

Comment: @LucasEstevam Não precisa se desculpar, o importante é aprender e não cometer os mesmos erros de novo :-) Outra coisa: se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na escolha do seu operador lógico. Substitua OR por AND:

```
if tipo_da_carne.lower() != "f" or tipo_da_carne.lower() != "a" or tipo_da_carne.lower() != "p":
```

Deixando:

```
if (tipo_da_carne.lower() != "f") and (tipo_da_carne.lower() != "a") and (tipo_da_carne.lower() != "p"):
```

Quando você digita F por exemplo, a primeira análise gera FALSE, mas as outras condicoes OR vao retornar TRUE (F nao é igual a A o que retorna TRUE), entrando no IF e no final, terminando o programa.